# return the row only if exists in python

Tags: python, django

I want to return the values only if the particular row exist but I couldn't able to achieve it.Here, what I tried

```
def CurrentRunning(UserId):
    
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetCurrentRunningActivity]  @UserId=%s', (UserId,))
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
        data= []    
        data.append({
                'TaskId':row[0],
                'Value1':row[1],
                'Value2' :row[2],
                'SelectedTeam':0 if row[3] is exists else row[3],
                'Level1':'0' if row[4] is exists else row[4],
                'Level2':'0' if row[5] is exists else row[5],
                'Level3':'0' if row[6] is exists else row[6],
                'Level4':'0' if row[7] is exists else row[7],
                'TotalVolume':'0' if row[8] is exists else row[8],
                'ReturnDate':'0' if row[9] is exists else row[9],
     
              })
                print('Activity')
                return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your if statement:

```
def CurrentRunning(UserId):

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetCurrentRunningActivity]  @UserId=%s', (UserId,))
    result_set = cursor.fetchall()
    data= []    
    data.append({
            'TaskId':row[0],
            'Value1':row[1],
            'Value2' :row[2],
            'SelectedTeam': row[3] if row[3] is not None else '0',
            'Level1': row[4] if row[4] is not None else '0',
            'Level2': row[5] if row[5] is not None else '0',
            'Level3': row[6] if row[6] is not None else '0'
            ...
            ...
```

and so on...

The code

```
val = row[3] if row[3] is not None else '0'
```

result in val == '0' when row[3] is None, else val will be equal to row[3].

If you are not sure if row[3] exist (maybe because the index 3 is greater than len(row)) you can add extra checks:

```
val = row[3] if ((row is not None) and (len(row)>3) and (row[3] is not None)) else '0'
```

Comment: I want to return zero if it doesn't exist @BioTubolo when `row[3]` doesn't exist just want to return as zero

Comment: check my edit :)